# Is it possible to access user's webcam by admin using RTCMultiConnection#V3

Tags: webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am creating Audio/Video/Text chat application. I have successfully completed Video conferencing functionality. But I don't have any idea about accessing User's webcam without user's permission.

What exactly I want to do is Admin can access user's webcam. I have created online user's list. When admin click on a button `Watch` of online user, admin should be able to access user's webcam, So that admin can see from that particular user's webcam.

Can any one guide me to do that?

[image]

Comment: It's not possible without user's permission. Send a request, U can send a customtrigger, which executes a getusermedia-function on sender site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Super admin can see all rooms, get video from any user from any room.**

You can use socket.io or otherwise PHP/mySQL to share rooms with the super-admin.

A super admin can view any user's video using "join" method:

```
var selectedUserId = database.getSelectedUserId();
connection.join(selectedUserId);
```

Super admin must set "dontCaptureUserMedia=true" to make sure he don't share his own camera. Which means that super-admin will seemlessly view videos from any user from any room.

```
connection.dontCaptureUserMedia = true;
var selectedUserId = database.getSelectedUserId();
connection.join(selectedUserId);
```

See how to [send or receive custom messages using socket.io](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/api.md#socketcustomevent) and try [a demo as well](https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/custom-socket-event.html).

**Here is an example code for super admin:**

```
connection.socketCustomEvent = 'super-admin-socket';
connection.dontCaptureUserMedia = true;
connection.connectSocket(function() {
    connection.socket.on(connection.socketCustomEvent, function(message) {
        if (message.newUser === true) {
            connection.join(message.userid);
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is code for all normal users. i.e. any user from any room:**

```
connection.socketCustomEvent = 'super-admin-socket';
connection.openOrJoin('any-room-id', function() {

    // this message is going toward super-admin
    // super-admin will receive this message
    // super-admin can view this user's camera seamlessly
    // or show his name in a list
    connection.socket.emit(connection.socketCustomEvent, {
        newUser: true,
        userid: connection.userid
    });
});
```

**See how to share rooms with super admin:**

Following code is for normal users:

```
connection.socketCustomEvent = 'super-admin-socket';
connection.openOrJoin('any-room-id', function() {
    // check if it is a room owner
    if (connection.isInitiator === true) {
        // room owner is sharing his room with super-adin
        connection.socket.emit(connection.socketCustomEvent, {
            newRoom: true,
            roomid: connection.sessionid
        });
    }
});
```

**Following code is for super admin:**

```
connection.socketCustomEvent = 'super-admin-socket';
connection.dontCaptureUserMedia = true;
connection.connectSocket(function() {
    connection.socket.on(connection.socketCustomEvent, function(message) {
        if (message.newUser === true) {
            connection.join(message.userid);
        }

        if (message.newRoom === true) {
            // display room in a list
            // or view room owner's video
            connection.join(message.roomid);
        }
    });
});
```

**Conclusion:**

> Super admin must have `userid` from any user to view his video.

Comment: is this possible with NodeJS?

Comment: what is `database.getSelectedUserId();` is this from database?

Comment: RTCMultiConnection-v3 uses nodesj/socket.io. Above snippets targets socket.io. Regarding "data.getSelectedUserId" it is just a hint. You can ignore that part (i.e. database.getSelectedUserId) because you can get all active rooms through socket.io. The last snippet shares room-id with super-admin using socket.io.